# Powershell - Sharepoint Auto file upload returning "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to upload a file to a sharepoint folder from C drive of my PC. But I am getting this error:

> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
>   At C:\Users\Projects\file_upload.ps1:18 char:1
>   + $webclient.UploadFile($destination +'/'+ $File.Name,'PUT', $File.Full ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

The code is :

```
 Add-Type -path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Add-Type -path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'



# Set the variables
$destination ='https://link to sharepoint site/foldername/'
$File =get-childitem 'C:\Users\path of the file in C drive'

# Since we’re doing this remotely, we need to authenticate
$securePasssword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('Username', $securePasssword)

# Upload the file
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = $credentials
$webclient.UploadFile($destination +'/'+ $File.Name,'PUT', $File.FullName)
```

If you could help me correct this code or suggest any other code which will work it would be a great help.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online ?

Comment: Are you aware thet `$destination` already ends in a slash and with `$destination +'/'` you are adding another one? Also `get-childitem` without filter or anything, will more than likely return an array of found FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects.

Comment: @theo, I have no idea, can you suggest the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the script below:

```
$User = "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com"  
$Password = '*******'  
$SiteURL = "https://Tenant.sharepoint.com"  
$Folder = "C:\Scripts\HpeQuota"  
#Path where you want to Copy  
$DocLibName = "Documents"  
#Docs library  
# Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required  for CSOM  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  
#Bind to site collection  
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)  
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))  
$Context.Credentials = $Creds  
#Retrieve list  
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)  
$Context.Load($List)  
$Context.ExecuteQuery()  
# Upload file  
Foreach($File in (dir $Folder  -File))  
{  
    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)  
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation  
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true  
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream  
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File  
  $Upload = $List.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("/Shared Documents/Cu folder").Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)    
    $Context.Load($Upload)  
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()  
}
```

[image]
[image]
Reference:

[SharePoint Online Automation - O365 - Upload Your Files Remotely Using PowerShell To SPO Document Library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-automation-o365-sharepoint-online-how-to-upload-your-files-r/)

Comment: it gives a lot of errors like , for  coms syntax is wrong, doesn't recognize retrieve as internal or external command.

Comment: Updated the code and result capture, please try again to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerry This works great and the file is succesfully uploaded to the Documents folder. Is there a tweak so that i may upload file to "Documents/Cu folder". Also the folder url shows as "site/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx" and when i put this in the site url am getting "There is no Web named
"/sites/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx/_vti_bin/sites.asmx"

Comment: Updated the code snippet to upload into "Documents/CU folder", please check, changed $upload line.